# Getting information from sysfs

Tags: sysfs, network-interface

I'm creating a script for polling information about network interfaces. For this I get some data from `/sysfs`.

Everything went fine until I wanted to clarify all possible states of an interface (Which are they btw? I'm aware for now only about `up`, `down` and `unknown`). I went through `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt` and found this:

> Accessing /sys/class/net/eth0/device is a bug in the application

Is there a reason for this?
Could someone explain me if I'm doing something wrong by getting information from `/sysfs`?

I don't iterate through all interfaces in `/sysfs` but get all network interfaces with `getifaddrs(3)`. Perhaps there is another method to get iface status?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the `device` link in class directories that you aren't supposed to use. The idea is that `/sys/class/net/eth0` is a symbolic link to somewhere under `/sys/devices`, and the `device` link merely links to a (grand-)<sup>*</sup>parent directory; instead of using the `device` link, you're supposed to walk back to a parent directory if needed.

Accessing files in `/sys/class/net/eth0/` is fine.

If you're refering to the operational status found in `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate`, there are a few more. The names are defined in [`net/core/net-sysfs.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/net-sysfs.c) and the constants in [`include/uapi/linux/if.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/if.h). They come from [RFC 2863](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2863#section-3.1.14).

Comment: Thanks. I figures out about device link after I posted the question already, but still wanted to hear some thoughts about the rest.